# GraphQLServer union types "Abstract type N must resolve to an Object type at runtime" error

Tags: typescript, graphql

Given a GraphQL `union` return type:

```
union GetBankAccountsResponseOrUserInputRequest = GetAccountsResponse | UserInputRequest
```

meant to be returned by a given resolver:

```
type Query {
  getBankAccounts: GetBankAccountsResponseOrUserInputRequest!
}
```

I'm getting these warnings or errors regarding a `__resolveType` or `__isTypeOf` function:

```
Abstract type N must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field Query.getBankAccounts with value { ..., __isTypeOf: [function __isTypeOf] }, received "undefined". Either the N type should provide a "resolveType" function or each possible type should provide an "isTypeOf" function.'
```

I've searched for days in github issues and SO questions looking to resolve this error.

Implementing `__resolveType` or `__isTypeOf` in my resolvers is not working:

```
export const Query = {
  getBankAccounts: (parent, args, context: IContext, info) => {
    return {
      __isTypeOf(obj) { // OR __resolveType, none of them work
        return `GetAccountsResponse`;
      },
      accounts: []
    };
  },
};
```

Comment: Returning a `__typename` property inside your resolver is perfectly fine (it utilizes the default type resolution logic), however, there's no reason why using `__resolveType` or `__isTypeOf` shouldn't work. What's missing from this question is what your actual implementation looked like and how this was included in your resolver map. Please edit your question to include the relevant code.

Comment: @DanielRearden I edited the question to add the relevant resolver implementation that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 6):

Since implementing `__resolveType` or `__isTypeOf` in my resolvers didn't work for me, I ended up solving this issue by adding the `__typename` directly into the resolver return Object.

In the `getBankAccounts` resolver implementation:

```js
async getBankAccounts(): GetBankAccountsResponseOrUserInputRequest {
    if (shouldGetUserInputRequest()) {
      return {
        __typename: "UserInputRequest",
        ...response,
      };
    }

    return {
      __typename: "GetAccountsResponse",
      accounts,
    };
  }
```

Hope that this helps somebody.

Answer (score 2):

Your resolver map is not set up correctly.

The resolver map passed to `ApolloServer` (or `makeExecutableSchema`) should should be an object whose keys are type names in your schema, with each key mapping to another object whose keys are field names on that type. Each field name then maps to a resolver function.

```
const resolvers = {
  SomeType: {
    someField: (parent, args, context, info) => { ... },
  },
}
```

You use the same resolver map to pass in the `resolveType` function for a union or interface. The pattern is the same, but the name of the type is the name of the union or interface and instead of a field name, the key is `__resolveType`:

```
const resolvers = {
  SomeType: {
    someField: (parent, args, context, info) => { ... },
  },
  SomeUnion: {
    __resolveType: (parent) => { ... },
  }
}
```

The `resolveType` function should always return a string that matches the name of an existing object type in your schema.

If you use `__isTypeOf` instead of `__resolveType`, then this will look a bit different because the `isTypeOf` function is associated with a particular object type, not the interface or union. [This is all shown in the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/unions-interfaces). So the resolver map looks like this:

```
const resolvers = {
  SomeType: {
    someField: (parent, args, context, info) => { ... },
    __isTypeOf: (parent) => { ... },
  },
}
```

`__isTypeOf` should always return either `true` or `false`, depending on whether the passed in object is in fact that type.

You only need to use either `__resolveType` or `__isTypeOf`. If you use `__isTypeOf`, you have to add it to every possible object type in the union or interface.

Comment: Right. So from my example, this `__resolveType` function should be put directly after `Query = { __resolveType }`, right?

Comment: No, because `Query` is not an abstract type whose type you need to resolve at runtime. `GetBankAccountsResponseOrUserInputRequest` is.